# Mark up declaration contained must be well formed

Tags: xml

As the title specifies, I'm newbie to XML and don't really know what exactly I'm missing. I'm pretty sure I mentioned all the elements but still  error comes up. Any help is really appreciated.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE persons[
    <!ELEMENT person (staff|student)>
    <!ELENEMT staff (name,age,gender,address,staffid,subject)>
    <!ELEMENT student (name,age,gender,address,rollno,standard,section)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT gender (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT address (doorno,street,city,state)>
    <!ELEMENT staffid (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT subject (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT rollno (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT standard (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT section (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT doorno (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
    ]>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You can learn more about our site by visiting the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. What exactly is your error - please tell us what you are trying to do, what you have already tried and where your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
<!ELENEMT staff (name,age,gender,address,staffid,subject)>
     ^^^
```

Comment: Oh crap!! Thanks.. So silly of me. I got frustrated and posted it here.. Thanks a bunch..